# Throwing exceptions outside of a method - Java

Tags: java, exception, throw, checked-exceptions

I am a beginner in Java.

I declared a method as `public void method() throws Exception`, but whenever I try to call that method in another area of the same class by using `method();`, I get an error:

```
Error: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

How can I use that method without getting this error?

Comment: When you call that method you need to either surround the invocation with a try-catch, or rethrow the Exception.

Comment: @azurefrog right, so would I call `method() throws Exception;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the other method that calls `method()`, you will have to somehow handle the exception that `method()` is throwing. At some point, it either needs to be caught, or declared all the way up to the `main()` method that started the whole program. So, either catch the exception:

```
try {
    method();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do what you want to do whenever method() fails
}
```

or declare it in your other method:

```
public void otherMethod() throws Exception {
    method();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

throws keyword is used to declare a Exception.
and throw keyword is used to explicitly throw an exception.
if u want to define a user define exception then ....

```
class exps extends Exception{
exps(String s){
    super(s);
 }
}

class input{
 input(String s) throws exps {
     throw new exps(s);
 }

}

public class exp{
 public static void main(String[] args){
     try{
         new input("Wrong input");
     }catch(exps e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
  }
}
```

Java try block is used to enclose the code that might throw an exception. It must be used within the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the `method()` call with a try-catch block somewhat like this:

```
try {
    method();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //do whatever
}
```

Or you can add a `throws` to the method in which `method()` is called.
example:

```
public void callingMethod() throws Exception {
    method();
}
```